# non complete proc boxplot in SAS

Tags: sas, boxplot, proc

I have this kind of code.

```
title 'Dispersion de Poids par chaque Produit et filiere';
proc sort data=tClassSASM; by filiere Produit PoidsN; run;
proc boxplot data=tClassSASM; 
    plot PoidsN*Produit/ nohlabel Vref=5,57,177 boxstyle=schematicid;
    label PoidsN='Poids Despersion (g)';
run;
```

This is the output. But whatever I do I cannot find how to delete the red crossed headline, regroup the variables marked in red and give colors to **vref** lines. Can you help ? 
[image: output]

Comment: Switch to SGPLOT instead of BOXPLOT. Or GTL.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming `filiere` takes on the values `X` and `Y`

Turn off ODS GRAPHICS so the cvref= plot option is used.

```
ods graphics off;

title 'Dispersion de Poids par chaque Produit et filiere';

proc sort data=tClassSASM; 
  by filiere Produit PoidsN; 
run;

proc boxplot data=tClassSASM; 

    * plot PoidsN*Produit/ nohlabel Vref=5,57,177 boxstyle=schematicid;

      plot PoidsN*filiere/ nohlabel Vref=5,57,177 cvref=RED boxstyle=schematicid;

    label PoidsN='Poids Despersion (g)';
run;
```

If you want a different color for each vref you will probably have to also use annotation data (anno= option).

Comment: Dear Richard, thank you for the response. But anyway I think it means nothing to have only the dispersion of each "filiere" as it is counting weights of apple, ball and third object. I wanted to know if it is possible to have a label which will be under each "Balle Pomme Volant" Group. For example. Balle Pomme Group for  Group X and Balle Pomme Volant for Group Y in the same graphics.

Comment: Ah, I took regroup to mean actually regroup, not label hierarchically.  What are the values of `filiere` ?